# Looking for a pure PowerShell IRC client

Tags: powershell, irc

I'm looking for a IRC client library/script written in PowerShell. The goal is to replace a `Perl` script that uses `Net::IRC` to communicate with a MindAlign channel.

SmartIrc4net will do in a pinch, but I'd rather have a pure implementation for simplicities sake.

Ideas?

Comment: Really?  Even the sockets and session management and everything?  Powershell is a very poor language for running daemons (this coming from its biggest fan).  Why not use/build an IRC client in an existing .Net language, then supply Powershell scripts as plugins?  Executing PS from .Net is very simple.

Comment: I don't want to run it as a server - just as a client to send progress messages to an operational channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ps1.soapyfrog.com/2007/01/31/irc-chat-bot-and-monitor/

Comment: Wow this was a long time ago! How would you use this to actually send a message to the channel? I can get it to trigger a block when a specific message is typed in the channel but I don't know how to correctly invoke _send or _notice.

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell command creates a bot named **monitor** that conencts to the given IRC server. It then specifies its body in a scriptblock, specifying to pipe all messages to the parent command. The output is then piped to Select-String (sls) to grep for "amazing."

`.\Run-IrcBot.ps1 monitor ircserver channel { if ($message.Text) { "/pipe " + $message.Text } } -Silent | sls amazing`

I was looking for a way to make IRC bots in PowerShell to run commands on demand. Didn't find something easy so I wrote my own little framework. A single-file download allows you to make fully-interactive IRC bots!

https://github.com/alejandro5042/Run-IrcBot